# How to get the value(ip address from interface) from the output and store it to variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

- I am writing a playbook task to get the IP address from the output and store the value and use it for other tasks.

## Ansible playbook

- name: Extract the secondary router ipsec tunnel address
  hosts: secondary
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  tags:

  - "sec_tunnel_ip"
    tasks:
  - name: Extract Tunnel1 ipsec interface address
    ios_command:
    commands: "sh ip int br | sec Tunnel1"
    register: save_tunn_out
  - debug:
    msg: "{{save_tunn_out.stdout}}"

I am getting the output like below:

ok: [172.16.12.1] => {
"msg": [
"Tunnel1                172.16.121.54   YES manual up                    up      \nTunnel100              10.0.0.101      YES manual up                    up"
]
}

But I want to extract the first ip interface output(for tunnel1) like below, and store it in a variable.

172.16.121.54

I am not sure how to get it without regex and store it on the variable.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use regex, which would be your best bet, you have to rely on splitting the string.

Assuming it will always be after Tunnel1 and followed by a space, you can do it like this.

```
  - name: Extract Tunnel1 ipsec interface address
    set_fact:
      save_tunn_out: "Tunnel1 172.16.121.54 YES manual up up \nTunnel100 10.0.0.101 YES manual up up"
  
  - name: Extract IP address
    debug:
      var: save_tunn_out.split("Tunnel1 ")[1].split(" ")[0]
```

Which gives you the desired output

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "save_tunn_out.split(\"Tunnel1 \")[1].split(\" \")[0]": "172.16.121.54"
}
```

To store in a variable afterward, you can use set_fact like this

```
  - name: Store in a variable
    set_fact:
      ip_address: "{{save_tunn_out.split('Tunnel1 ')[1].split(' ')[0]}}"

  - name: Debug variable
    debug:
      msg: "Ip address is : {{ip_address}}"
```

Output :

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Ip address is : 172.16.121.54"
}
```

Comment: If you're new to splitting string and want a more detailed explanation, let me know.